# What are these iPad Ethernet devices?

Tags: macos, ios, ipad, network

When I plug an iPad into my laptop (M1 MacBook Pro running Monterey) two Ethernet ports show up in my Network Services with IP addresses in the 169.254.* range.

What are these used for?

*I ask because these devices cause problems when I'm using an iPad [NDI](https://www.ndi.tv/) receiver which tries to use these IP addresses instead of the correct 192.168. address.*

[image]

### Update

Note that these services don't show up in Network Preferences, so it's nothing to do with service order:
[image]
(note that this is on a different network so the IP addresses won't match up between screenshots)

Comment: So, is the Mac connecting to the wrong network device? Change the "Service Order" in System PRefs > Network.

Comment: No it's that NDI looks for the IP address with the lowest number when establishing a connection - network service order makes no difference: https://forums.newtek.com/threads/mac-to-ios-connection-troubles.166804)